# Idiomatic way to get every digit of a number

Tags: clojure

What's the idiomatic way to get each digit of a number and put them into a sequence?

Currently I'm doing

```
(map #(Integer/parseInt %) (map str ((comp seq str) 123456)))
```

, which is somewhat ugly...

Any ideas?

Comment: sounds like someone is working on a PCG puzzle :)

Comment: Er... What's a PCG puzzle? :)

Comment: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/25003/sort-a-number-sorta

Comment: Oh, that PCG! I'll look into that @SirBraneDamuj

Comment: That's pretty nice @apai , is there anything more compact?

Comment: I believe there are also some Project Euler problems for which you could use this.

Comment: Change your comment into answer so I can vote up, @apai

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
(for [n  (str 123456)] 
     (- (byte n) 48))
```

Answer (score 6):

```
 (map #(Character/getNumericValue %) (str 123456))
```

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
(defn digits
    [x]
    (if (< x 10)
        [x]
        (conj (digits (quot x 10))
              (rem x 10))))

user=>(digits 123456)
[1 2 3 4 5 6]
```

Answer (score 4):

I think it's nice to write this with lazy sequences, even if you can't actually use the laziness because you're building it from the "wrong" end:

```
(defn digits [x]
  (rseq (mapv #(rem % 10)
              (->> x
                   (iterate #(quot % 10))
                   (take-while pos?)))))
```

If you want, you can write a digits* that doesn't use mapv or rseq, and lazily returns the digits in backwards order.

Comment: I like yours stylistically better, but it runs slower for me. Is there a way to speed this one up?

Comment: I can't imagine this being a bottleneck in any reasonable Clojure app. Who cares if it's not blazing fast?

Comment: Nobody! But I find as a learning exercise that I learn a lot when I try to speed things up.

Comment: Taking a lazy seq is very cool, but it seems like @Ankur's answer is more compact and we don't usually have very long digit numbers...